# Corona built apk won't install on Samsung Galaxy S2

Tags: android, android-emulator, lua, coronasdk

I have tried many of the solutions offered in answer to this question but nothing is working. I tried to install A corona apk file on the eclipse android emulator but I get this error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb install Stuck_scen
es_new.apk
119 KB/s (4927673 bytes in 40.242s)
        pkg: /data/local/tmp/Stuck_scenes_new.apk
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the apk generated has not been signed by a certificate.
Follow any of the methods mentioned in this [page](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Specifically you could use this command to sign your app

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore
my_application.apk alias_name
```

Comment: This helped me out, but I found out that my real problem was that the JDK 7 uses a different encryption to JDK 6 and this is the cause of the error. All I had to do was remove jdk 7 from PATH in my environmental variables and it worked for me